# Ora - 00472 - PMON process terminated with error (ORACLE)

Tags: oracle

i am technical support in our company, We have encountered this error "Ora-00472" , Also it shows from the SVRMGR23 in ORACLE when connecting to the database, it shows "connected to an idle instance". How can i fix this error?

Thank you,

Comment: Please Help! Thank you,

Comment: This is a question for Server Fault. But chances are good you have to shutdown abort, startup force, and then spend some money to upgrade from a version that is over 20 years old.

Comment: Hi sir, thank you for your reply and suggestions sir, we are using oracle7, it's really an old server sir, is their any other way for us to solve this problem for the mean time sir?

Comment: I promise you the folks on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) will be much more helpful to you because this question will be on topic. If you have a question about software you are writing, then this is the place for you. Otherwise, you'll want to look at [other communities](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: Check the alert.log of the Database, if nothing suspicious goes there, try `sqlplus / as sysdba SQL> startup`

Comment: Do you know sir, where alert.log can be found?